# A transaction that does not get processed

Tags: transactions, mtgox, blockchain.info, confirmations

Yesterday I moved 20 bitcoins from my wallet in MtGox to my personal wallet, twice. The two transactions were made in a short time (about 1 minute). Both were done toward the same recipient: 142fUrgXNJiKwhXWiN9gkR8zvTbucm2idA
The ID of the first transaction was:

63eddec307c6ab9bf285b6b33f506fe90069e5d297263ed55249580a8120fff7

And of the second was: 67d1c656a65dc4c29f20292f4abecdb45d5a492091a167a0643fd50723f61dbf

Both transactions were registered from my MtGox account lowering it of said amount (thus taking away the possibility to try again). 
Well, the first appeared immediately in my wallet, And after a few minutes gathered the confirmations necessary, and is now happily sitting there. The second never appeared. It did however appear on Blockchain:
https://blockchain.info/tx/67d1c656a65dc4c29f20292f4abecdb45d5a492091a167a0643fd50723f61dbf

Where it is sitting in a queue from yesterday evening with a confirmation warning saying: **"This transaction has a none standard input"**.

So I would like to understand what is going on. What shall I do to recover those bitcoins?

Thanks,
Pietro

P.S. Note that making a search on the warning on google shows only one result: the code in github. So no one must have had this problem before. Weird.

[image: Image of block chain with the warning visible]

Comment: Now it is saying that the second transaction is a double spend. https://blockchain.info/tx-index/96170453
But MtGox took away 20 bitcoin TWICE from my account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually 20 BTC arrived. But not from THAT transaction. Maybe MtGox realising that they made an error sent another extra 20. Weird.

Comment: That's perfectly normal for high-volume, robust transaction submission. They're executing many, many payments, so they can't wait to see if each one succeeds before issuing the next one. That means they may have some "transaction chains" that fail. As soon as a transaction can be assured of not processing, a different transaction can be issue in its place. Gox has many, many outputs and inputs they're juggling at the same time -- they can't always use old coins because their old coins are in cold storage.